# Rxjs: Is the observable born out of asObservable method of Subject the same as the source Subject?

Tags: rxjs

According to the source code in rxjs,
asObservable implementation is like this:

```
asObservable(): Observable<T> {
  const observable = new Observable<T>();
  (<any>observable).source = this;
  return observable;
}
```

And I found out, when the source `Subject`emits a value using `next`, the observable also emits the data to the observers which subcribe the observable. This quite much answers my question. But what confuses me is that why we would need `asObservable` method? Can't we just use `Subject` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`asObservable` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Subject.ts#L125-L129) returns an `Observable` that has the subject as its `source`:

```ts
export class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements ISubscription {
  ...
  asObservable(): Observable<T> {
    const observable = new Observable<T>();
    (<any>observable).source = this;
    return observable;
  }
}
```

The point of the method is to create an observable that mirrors the subject, without exposing the subject's methods. That observable can then be returned to a caller.

If the subject itself were to be returned, a caller would be able to invoke the subject's `next`, `error` and `complete` methods. With the observable returned by `asObservable`, that's not possible.

Comment: Then, what about the multicast/unicast issue? As far as I know, originally, `Observable` is unicast and `Subject` is multicast. If we make an observable using `asObservable`, would it stay multicast like `Subject` which is the source of it?

Comment: An `Observable` can be unicast or multicast - indeed, a `Subject` **is** an `Observable`. (As an example, the observables created by `fromEvent` are multicast.) `asObservable` returns an observable that exactly mirrors the subject - subscribers to the observable will be indirectly subscribed to the subject.

Comment: I knew `Observable` could be multicast but when it's created, I thought it's unicast. Am I wrong?

Comment: The returned observable is multicast. Observables can be either hot or cold (i.e. multicast or unicast). The fundamental part of this answer is that the subscription to the observable returned by `asObservable` is an indirect subscription to the subject - so it's hot/multicast. That is, all subscribers to the observable will see the same notifications.

Comment: I've checked out the article you linked above. Based on my understanding, `Subjects` are multicast and since the observable which we get as the result of `asObservable` mirrors the subject, it's multicast as well. The only thing is that how could we possibly assure it must be hot observable? They say, hot and cold are determined by the way its(observable) relation with `Producer`. So I guess the observable is multicast but the hot and cold issue would depend on the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Think about it this way: observables are cold if subscribing to them creates the notification source. For example, subscribing to a `timer` observable creates the timer (and unsubscribing destroys the timer). Each subscriber to a cold observable receives its own notifications. Subscribing to the observable returned by `asObservable` does not create the notification source - the subject's source is the source - so the observable is hot. It really is as simple as that. And hot is synonymous with multicast, because all subscribers to a hot observable receive the same notifications.